# Second NIC with Macvlan on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking, macvlan

I need to add a second interface to some of the specific K8s pods on GKE that need to be accessible directly from public users on the Internet. So I used Multus and defined a Macvlan cni like this:

```
apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: macvlan-conf
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
      "type": "macvlan",
      "master": "eth0",
      "mode": "bridge",
      "ipam": {
        "type": "host-local",
        "subnet": "10.162.0.0/20",
        "rangeStart": "10.162.0.100",
        "rangeEnd": "10.162.0.150",
        "routes": [
          { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" }
        ],
        "gateway": "10.162.0.1"
      }
    }'
```

10.162.0.1 is the default gateway of my K8s nodes in GCP. So, I imagine that in this case, pods should have the access to the outside. But in pods, just there is one default gateway that routes the internal pods traffic. Also, I can't add any route because of the privileges issues.

**Question:**

My expectation is wrong? How I should use Macvlan to create a public interface for those pods?

Comment: Also I created a new IP alias for k8s and used that range for Macvlan, but just pods on the same node can pin each other, not pods on other nodes or outside network.

Comment: Were you able to access the pod directly from the internet?